# Change color of histogram after it was plotted

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

How can I change the color of a histogram after I draw it? (using hist)

```
z = hist([1,2,3])
z.set_color(???) < -- Something like this
```

also how can I check what color is the histogram

```
z = hist([1,2,3])
color = z.get_color(???) < -- also Something like this
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such functions exist. You just need to store the `patches` returned by `hist` and access the `facecolor` of each of them:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n, bins, patches = plt.hist([1,2,3])
for p in patches:
    print p.get_facecolor()
    p.set_facecolor((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
```

Output:

```
(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0)
(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0)
(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0)
(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0)
(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0)
(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0)
(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0)
(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0)
(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0)
(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Note that you get one patch per bin. By default `hist` plots 10 bins. You might want to define it differently using `plt.hist([1,2,3], bins=3)`.